# Set random negative number with Random Functions in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

How can i set random negative number in Message content in AMQP publisher via JMETER?
I try this:

```
"customerId": ${__Random(-1, -100 )}
```

but response message is: time out.

If I set:

```
"customerId": ${__Random(1, 100 )}
```

response is work.

How can i set negative range in this field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you're telling it to find a number bigger than -1 and smaller than -100, of which no numbers exist.

${__Random(min, max)} this is really what is happening so the smaller number goes first then the larger number.

try "customerId": ${__Random(-100, -1 )}